# gzip json compression Tomcat 8

Tags: compression, gzip, tomcat8

I'm trying to use gzip compression on Tomcat 8 JSON requests, I've added the following attributes to the connector in the server.xml

```
useSendfile="false" compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json,application/pdf,application/xhtml+xml"
```

however, in the rest call, it still does not use Content-Encoding gzip in the response headers.

Request header:

```
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
```

Reponse header sample:

```
Content-Type    application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

no HTTP header field of Content-Encoding is being shown in the response header.

any idea?